# c# int and string a same value but come with two different number

Tags: c#

Good Day !
I'm having a problem which is when I do a SQL query and want to return an int value, that queries suppose to return a **zero** value, but when I get int it will automatic becomes **48**, but when I get from string then it is **zero**, here is my code

```
string SQLCtn = @"SELECT sum(t7.Qty) AS Ctn 
                        FROM dbFBHDR t1, dbFBDTL t7, dbProduct t3 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbClass t4 
                        ON t3.PClass = t4.Class LEFT OUTER JOIN dbCategory t5 
                        ON t3.PClass = t5.Class 
                        AND t3.PCategory = t5.Category LEFT OUTER JOIN dbType t6 
                        ON t3.PClass = t6.Class 
                        AND t3.PCategory = t6.Category 
                        AND t3.PType = t6.PType 
                        WHERE t7.ProductCode = t3.Code 
                        AND t3.PClass = '" + PDC.classBeer + "' " +
                        "AND t3.PCategory >= '" + PDC.catBeerFrom + "' " +
                        "AND t3.PCategory <= '" + PDC.catBeerTo + "' " +
                        "AND t3.PType = '" + PDC.typeCTN + "' " +
                        "AND t1.Status = 'CLOSED' " +
                        "AND t1.CashNo = t7.CashNo " +
                        "AND t1.Branch = t7.Branch " +
                        "AND t1.CashDate >= '" + PDC.DateFrom + "' " +
                        "AND t1.CashDate <= '" + PDC.DateTo + "' " +
                        "AND t1.Branch = '" + PDC.branch + "' " +
                        "AND extract(hour from CheckInTime) >= '0' " +
                        "AND extract(hour from CheckInTime) <= '9999'";

        FbCommand cmdCTN = new FbCommand(SQLCtn, FbCon);
        cmdCTN.ExecuteNonQuery();
        FbDataReader readerCTN = cmdCTN.ExecuteReader();
        while (readerCTN.Read() == true)
        {
            int iCTN;
            string sCTN;

            if (readerCTN["Ctn"].ToString() == "")
            {
                iCTN = '0';
                sCTN = "0";
                MessageBox.Show("" + iCTN + "", "int");
                MessageBox.Show("" + sCTN + "", "string");
            }
            else
            {
                iCTN = readerCTN.GetInt32(readerCTN.GetOrdinal("Ctn"));
                sCTN = readerCTN.GetString(readerCTN.GetOrdinal("Ctn"));
                MessageBox.Show("" + iCTN + "", "int");
                MessageBox.Show("" + sCTN + "", "string");
            }
        }
```

And this is the result

[Result with int](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sju5N.png)

[Result with string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lgFv.png)

Comment: Why are there still people that haven't read the [SQL Injection wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)   :*(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You converted the `char` `'0'` to `int`, so you see its ASCII code `48`.

Just assign `0`, `iCTN = 0;`

Comment: the **char** is from SQL ?

Comment: @TeoLawrence no, the char is from the line `iCTN = '0';`.

Comment: @TeoLawrence I gave the solution in my answer, use the int `0`.

Comment: I see ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

To clarify Guy's answer, computers view all data as [Binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) which is a system of numbers much like the decimal system we're familiar with.

There's no such thing as an "A", a "b", a "6" or any other letter to a computer. In fact even "0" and "1", the numbers we use to count binary are just how we represent what a computer sees.

In order to represent letters and numbers in a string we use a convention. One of the earliest and widely used is [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) (but others like [UTF](https://unicode-table.com/en/) exist too).

If you look at the table for ASCII, the number '0' is represented at 48, the letter 'A' is 65 and the letter 'a' is 97. To the computer they are always the numbers 48, 65 and 97 but if you tell the computer to treat them as a character or a string it will represent them to the screen as '0', 'A', and 'a' for you.

To a computer `int foo = '0';` is the same as `int foo = 48;`
And similarly `char bar = 65;` is the same as `char bar = 'A';`

Comment: And in Unicode (of which UTF8 is one of the byte representations) the first 128 characters are at identical positions to their ASCII equivalent. ASCII doesn't go beyond that, Unicode does.

Comment: Without saying what you mean by ASCII being widely used, it's pretty misleading. ASCII is not used in .NET text data types.